# how to add version info for linux applications

Tags: linux, shell, console, version

I have developed a GUI application in linux. 
Currently, the version information of the application is displayed inside the GUI.
Now, my customer wants that he should be able to check version of the application by typing following command:

```
[shell]: appName --version
```

What I have done is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* Initialize Qt Application */
    QApplication simulatorGUI(argc, argv);

    QStringList argList = simulatorGUI.arguments();

    if((argList.count() == 2) && (argList[1].toStdString() == "--version"))
    {
        cout << "App Simulator V2.3" << endl;
    }

    simulatorGUI.setStyle(new QCleanlooksStyle);
        appSimulator simulatorInstance;
        simulatorInstance.show();
        return simulatorGUI.exec();
}
```

Using this code I am able to check version information of my application as:

```
[shell]: ./appSimulator --version      
App Simulator V2.3
```

And to run the application, I use following command:

```
[shell]: ./appSimulator
```

**My doubt is:**
1. Is this the correct way of implementation?
2. Is there a better way to implement the same? Can I achieve something like:

```
[shell]: appSimulator --version
```

instead of

```
[shell]: ./appSimulator --version
```

??

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to implement the `appsSiulator --help` program argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be sufficient. The ./ is dependant on your path, so if the program can be found in your path, you won't need it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more doubt: How can I have an application which is called from anywhere without using ./ ?? I believe it has something to do with addition in bin.

Comment: It has to do with the `PATH` environment variable which you could update e.g. in your `.login` or `.profile` or `.bashrc` initialization files for `bash`